# why to we put to a map and add to a list

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

I noticed that some of the api's use *add* like `view.addOnTouchListner()` while some other is using *put* like `intent.putExtra()` . While inspecting further it i found that when the underlying data structure is map we *put* and when the underlying data structure is list we use *add* .

so how do we determine whether name the method *put* or *add* ? is there any reason one is *put* and the other is *add*?

Comment: Map exposes `put` while List exposes `add`.  This is one obvious explanation for the naming convention.

Comment: `add` implies that you are adding, meaning that if you call it n times, you will actually find n  objects (querying/getting it back). `put` doesn't

Comment: maybe "put" involves assosication of key and value and "add" is for simply adding item in the list.

Comment: Joshua Bloch designed and implemented those interfaces for List and Map.  I like Blackbelt's point, but the ultimate answer would come from JB.

Comment: `Map.put()` may overwrite an existing mapping, so `add` would be the wrong word to use.

Comment: @Blackbelt 's comment makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map a key to a value, use *put*, if you need to add to a list that allows duplicates, use *add*.

That being said, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) on each Intent.putExtra() method begins with:

> **Add** extended data to the intent.

But maybe it should say

> **Put** extended data to the intent.